# Why can't I read signs in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On Minecraft PE before the 9.5 update I could read signs perfectly, now I can't. Well I can, but the sign has to be two blocks up and I have to go really close. So I can't see lower and high signs.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try breaking and re-placing them?

Answer (score 3):

If your signs are being affected by the lighting bug (introduced in 0.9) and look like this:

[image]

You can fix this by going to Options and turning Fancy Graphics off.

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can try:

1. Restart the game
2. Destroy and replace the sign
3. Attempt on another single player world
4. Chang graphic settings..

Extreme (Back-up maps)

- Delete and reinstall the game if it really bothers you...

Hope this helped :)