# I can't read signs on my minecraft pocket edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

**These problems are for Minecraft PE on Kindle Fire HD**

My problem is that I can barely read signs. To read a sign I have to stand in a certain place and look in a certain direction and it can take ages for me to find out where that is. I have turned fancy graphics off and it still didn't work. I used to be able to see them but now I can't.

Can someone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. I've looked on different sites but they aren't very helpful.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade. Please take a look at the [tour]! This site is getting answers, so please limit your question to a single question, and make another one for the second one. Luckily for you, [this question has a solution to your friend's "Invalid Name" issue](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222302/how-do-i-get-on-a-minecraft-pe-server-when-it-says-invalid-name), so there's no need for the second question (unless it does not solve the issue after all). I suggest you [edit] your question (including the title) to concentrate on the first question.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203980/why-cant-i-read-signs-in-minecraft-pe

Comment: @MrLemon the sign one doesn't help. I've tried them all and they are still unreadable.

Comment: Related Bug Tracker Entry: [\[MCPE-6450\] Sign text is not visible from a distance](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-6450)

Comment: Have you tried:
Relogging,
Placing A Torch Nearby

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with Kindles, as they get all the minecraft updates first, even when they are not completely finished. Luckily for you, a new update for minecraft has just come out which should fix this problem as well as add the cartoon texture pack. Just update your minecraft and it should work.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Kindles no longer get new updates first. In fact, they tend to receive the updates weeks or even months after other platforms.

Comment: @ZachTalonGamesYT ever since Bedrock has formed, all the updates come out at the same time. Different versions would not allow cross-play

Comment: Thats exactly the problem. The kindle falls behind, and typically cannot play with anybody who isn't also on a kindle. Also, Windows 10, Xbox, and Android devices get new updates first. iOS gets updates the same day, but they usually release several hours later. Any other device gets updates days or weeks later, except kindle, which, as I said before, dont get updates for weeks to months. The Update Aquatic wasn't released for Kindle for almost a year after it released for other devices.